# Evaluating $\int_{0}^{x}\frac{\arctan(t)}{t}dt-\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{x}}\frac{\arctan(t)}{t}dt$

Tags: definite-integrals

The paper here https://www.imsc.res.in/~rao/ramanujan/collectedpapers/Integral/Integral1.htm says that, $\int_{0}^{x}\frac{\arctan(t)}{t}dt-\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{x}}\frac{\arctan(t)}{t}dt=\frac{1}{2}\pi\ln(x)$

I tried verifying this result graphically using Desmos. But the graph seems oddly off. It looks like the answer must be $\pi\ln(x)$ and not $\frac{1}{2}\pi\ln(x)$.
[image: Here is the graph]

Any help ? Thanks :)

Comment: Make the substitution $u = \frac{1}{t}$ in the second integral, and then use the fact that $\arctan(x) + \arctan(\frac{1}{x}) = \frac{\pi}{2}$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint**. You may differentiate the function given by
$$
f(x)=\int_{0}^{x}\frac{\arctan(t)}{t}dt-\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{x}}\frac{\arctan(t)}{t}dt, \qquad x>0,
$$ obtaining
$$
f'(x)=\frac{\arctan(x)}{x}-\left(-\frac1{x^2} \right)\frac{\arctan(\frac1x)}{\frac1x}=\frac{\arctan(x)+\arctan(\frac1x)}{x}, \quad x>0,
$$ then one may recall that
$$
\arctan x+\arctan\frac1x=\frac \pi2,\qquad x>0,
$$that is 
$$
f'(x)=\frac \pi2 \: \frac1x, \quad x>0.
$$Observe that $f(1)=0$.

I hope you can take it from here.

The case $x<0$ is similar.

Comment: Hi Olivier ! I was typing the same when your answer came ! Cheers.

Comment: Hi Claude! Thanks. I hope you are doing well.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I have one doubt, the graphs of $f(x)$ and $\int_{0}^{x}\frac{\arctan(t)}{t}-\int_{0}^{1/x}\frac{\arctan(t)}{t}$ don't really match. But the graph of $\pi\ln(x)$ and the the latter matches, atleast around $|x|<1$. Why is that so ? I have also attached a graph in the question.

Comment: My bad. I typed in $\log(x)$ and not $\ln(x)$. Sorry